# How to add a proper fillet to corner of a cuboid in Fusion 360?

Tags: fusion360

I am a total beginner to Fusion 360. I need to add a fillet. Look at the picture to get better idea.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are probably many ways to do this, this method describes how I do this.

First you need to `fillet` the top, then you `chamfer` the edges.

Create a lid:
[image]

Fillet the corner edges:
[image]

Chamfer the lid edges:
[image]